# Trying to add a class attribute based on a specific month

Tags: javascript

I have a table setup where I add a particular class based on the month. I'm using Javascript for this. Right now, I cannot seem to consistently get the class to be added based on my Javascript if statements. I have the following code:

```
var now = new Date();
      var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
      var month = now.getMonth();
      var date = now.getDate();
      var year = now.getFullYear();
      var hour = now.getHours();


     if (month == 7 && 8 && 9)
     $('.winter').addClass('TableRowColor');


     else if (month == 10 && 11 && 0)
     $('.spring').addClass('TableRowColor');


     else if (month == 1 && 2 && 3)
     $('.summer').addClass('TableRowColor');


     else if (month == 4 && 5 && 9);
     $('.fall').addClass('TableRowColor');
     {
}
```

I'm testing my code logic using the very last 'else if' statement that contains the 'fall' class. Since we are currently in the month of July, and NOT the 4th, 5th or 9th month, I wouldn't think .fall class would get applied, yet it still does. What am I doing wrong?

When I take away the semi colon after `else if (month == 4 && 5 && 9);` the class doesn't get applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `month == 7 && 8 && 9` syntax? Anyway, walk through your code with a debugger and look at which statements are getting executed and what the variable values are.

Comment: `month == 7 && 8 && 9` should propably be `month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 9` [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: if it is month 7 and 8 and 9 add x class. I did have (month == 7 || 8 || 9) but that was the same thing.

Comment: @Marlon please check out a basic JS tutorial, including the section on conditionals.

Comment: Torazaburo, what sort of debugger? I use Chrome, but I'm not sure how to check out scripts.

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, drop everything else you are doing and learn now. Start with F12.

Answer (score -1):

You have a semi colon at the end of that last else if. Is that in the code you're actually running?  Explanation: looks like the fall class is always added because it's not enclosed in an if statement due to that misplaced semicolon.

Comment: Yes, and the class is added, but when I take away the semi colon the class is not added, even if I change that '9' to a '6' just to see if the class will be added for the current month we're in.

Comment: This is a problem, but not the main problem.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't want the || logical operator?